# Problem with updating web reference in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, web-reference

The Problem is that I have a web reference genereted from WSDL file.
Now I have new WSDL but the old location where the WSDL was erlier is not accesible.
Where I can change the path to the new WSDL to do update web reference?
When I delete my old web reference and add new one with the same name, I don't see the web reference namespace anymore in code classes...any ideas??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on what type your reference is.

If it's a Service reference, then you can change it by right click on that reference and choose "Configure Service Reference". In service reference settings window you will see "Address" field. There you can change your service reference address.

If it's a Web reference, then select that web reference and press F4 key to open Properties window. There you can change your web reference url address.

Comment: it's a web one but the Full Path property is disabled :(

Comment: But the problem is that on the Full path I have Sommething like E:\_DEV\_DEV\CS2New\2WWW\App_WebReferences\Service\ but when I click update web reference I get There was an error downloading file:///F:/_DEV.... I think it's because the project was created on different machine :/ any ideas now?

Comment: Copy WSDL to your local machine and set web reference to your local machine WSDL file.. like: C:\test.wsdl

Answer (score 3):

1. In the solution Explorer in VS choose the web reference.
2. In the Properties panel you'll find Web Reference URL, change it to the new value.
3. Update web reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using WSDL / svcutil to generate the proxy, specify the /namespace option.